# text back to R object in tm package

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus

I am new to the `tm` package and would be grateful for help. I have a bunch of posts that I've extracted unnecessary symbols and stopwords from, which I have done  using the various functions of the `tm` package (see below).  At the end, I am left with 201 documents that contain the clean strings that I need, however, it is not an R object but rather a `VCorpus` object.  How should can I stitch these processed documents all into one text file so that it becomes one long string ?

In other words, how can one convert a VCorpus object to a dataframe or list or another R object?

```
corpus <-iconv(posts$message, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)

#remove speical characters for emails

for(j in seq(corpus))   
{   
  corpus[[j]] <- gsub("/", " ", corpus[[j]])   
  corpus[[j]] <- gsub("@", " ", corpus[[j]])   
  corpus[[j]] <- gsub("\\|", " ", corpus[[j]])   
}   


library(SnowballC)

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)  

#remove common English stopwords 
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#remove words that will be common in our given context
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("department", "email", "job", "fresher", "internship"))

#removeUrls
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeURL)

> corpus
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 201
```

Comment: Do not edit your question to a completely different question. Open a new question instead.

Answer (score 3):

The Corpus is a list of plain text documents. If you want to extract all the content as a character array, you can use `sapply` and `content` to loop over the list to extract all the content

Tested using

```
# library(tm)
data("crude")
x <- tm_map(crude, stemDocument, lazy = TRUE)
x <- tm_map(x, content_transformer(tolower))

xx <- sapply(x, content)
str(xx)
```

Use `lapply` rather than `sapply` if you want a list.

Comment: I receive the following error when I replace your data with my own : `Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: Then you should provide a reproducible example in your question so I can see how your corpus is different form the sample I created. It looks like your `removeURL` should be wrapped in a `content_transformer`. I suggest you read the documentation for the latter function.